# send sms from one mobile to another mobile via bluetooth using j2me

Tags: java, java-me, bluetooth, sms

i need to send sms (text string) from one mobile to another mobile using bluetooth. Im developing this using J2ME.

I know basics of J2ME and midlets. And have managed to detect active mobile bluetooth device in proximity.

What all java library files and functions would i need to send an sms?

Comment: I think that really depends on the phone's manufacturer. I doubt there's an API common to all phones. It'll be different depending on the platform.

Comment: Do you know where i can get a documentation of such API? For nokia mobiles maybe.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701551/why-does-my-j2me-bluetooth-code-hangs-after-an-incoming-rfcomm-connection .. its the same concept just `out.write` with the SMS you wan to send

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "send SMS over bluetooth".

If you are looking for a way to send a piece of text from one handset to another, a good bet would be to create a MIDlet to use JSR 82 OBEX to send a string with the MIME header `text/plain` -- on some handsets this will be interpreted as an incoming note which can then be read.

For a full Bluetooth chat system, you would need a receiving MIDlet on the other side, and probably to create your own custom protocol between them.

There are [already](http://sourceforge.net/projects/toothfairy/) apps out there which do this.